# Unity Cool Down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making my first game and I have one last thing left to do. I have a shop where you can buy a lot of stuff. One of them obstacles don't spawn, but it was OP. So I decided to make a button that would do this effect for 10 seconds and have it cool down 20s before the next use. I tried the known for me methods but in this case they didn't work. I just want the boolean to change to true and after 10 seconds to false and to be cool down 20s before it can be pressed again. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT:

So this is my code for on click button event:

```
    public static bool isActive;
public Animator anim;

void use()
{
    isActive = true;
    anim.SetBool("isAngry", true);
}

void stop()
{
    isActive = false;
    anim.SetBool("isAngry", false);
}

public void clickButton()
{
    StartCoroutine("start");
}

IEnumerator start ()
{
    while (true)
    {
        use();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
        stop();
    }
}
```

and this is my code for obstacles:

```
   void Start()
{
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    StartCoroutine(obstaclesWave());
}

private void spawnObstacles()
{
    GameObject a = Instantiate(obstaclesPrefab) as GameObject;
    a.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), screenBounds.y);
}

IEnumerator obstaclesWave()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
        if(usePszczoła.isActive == false)
            spawnObstacles();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When the button is pressed make a note of the time, disable the button, and start the effect. When 10 seconds has passed stop the effect. When 30 seconds has passed enable the button.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show code examples of what you've done. What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: @Hayden I've edited the post

Comment: so, the button is working, but when i click the button it just stops the spawning forever

Comment: the cool down is working because Debug Log is showing when i clicked again button too fast, but as I said the spawning is stopped forever

Comment: By the way, calling Coroutine by string (IEnumerator's name) should be avoided. Consider `StartCoroutine(start())`.

Comment: Ok, i change it

Comment: "usePszczoła" is the class of 1st code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use Coroutine. Simple code here:

```
        private bool isCooldown = false;

        public void ActivateSkill()
        {
            if (!isCooldown)
            {
                // Activate Skill
                StartCoroutine(_ActivateSkillCoroutine());
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("The skill is in cooldown!");
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator _ActivateSkillCoroutine()
        {
            // Sets that this skill is on cooldown.
            isCooldown = true;

            // activate your skill, and wait for the end of it's effect.
            yield return _SkillEffect();

            // then wait for it's cooldown.
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);

            // after 20 seconds, sets that the skill is ready to use.
            isCooldown = false;
        }

        private IEnumerator _SkillEffect()
        {
            // 10 seconds for your skill. Try implement it yourself!
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
        }
```

This code is mere example, so you will be able to find your own way to do this.

More references : [UnityEngine.Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)

Edit: As I see in your code, It seems like your code is, when the button is clicked, it stops spawning and waits for 10 seconds, and enables spawning, and *immediatly* stops spawning for 10 seconds, which loops forever. Try this:

```
private bool isCooldown = false
IEnumerator start ()
{
    if (isCooldown) yield break;

    isCooldown = true;

    use();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    stop();

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    isCooldown = false;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210587/discussion-on-answer-by-mybug18-unity-cool-down).